# How can I transfer media in a loselessstate? Photos app VS Image Capture VS Air Drop

Tags: iphone, photos, data-synchronization, airdrop, image-capture

Trying to back up over 11k of photos and videos.
(Back them up as in have a copy of every photo and video stored on backup media (NAS + external drive + my own cloud) as individual photo and video files outside of the "backup" process for iPhone. So, basically download all media without loss of quality)

It seems there are at least 3 ways to do it without iCloud: Photos app, Image Capture, Air Drop.
I've been trying to research which way is better, and stumbled onto this vid (it's not in English, but I understood the general point):

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/nVa8Z2Okuv8

...and it seems to suggest that both Photos app and Image Capture alter the file in some way as they extract it from the iPhone - either compressing it or removing edits history/metadata.

On the other hand, Airdropping 11000+ files would suck as well, as my experience (and multiple online posts) tells me that airdrop bugs out when you try to transfer more than ~500 files in one go, probably even less if the files are big (e.g., videos).

So, is there a definitive spec for each method: what the quality loss and best practices is?

Comment: Hi! I’m going to make a small edit, but we’re missing a bit of detail. Backup means you won’t access the images it’s just something that can be restored. Is that what you want or do you want to export in an archive the source photos to another place that isn’t just for restoring to a new or erased iPhone?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Back them up as in have a copy of every photo and video stored on backup media (NAS + external drive + my own cloud) outside of the "backup" process for iPhone.

So, basically download all media without loss of quality. Seems like Apple quietly alters the original media when downloading it from iPhone at least with some download methods. I wanted clarity which methods allow to obtain a copy of media verbatim VS which methods lead to any kind of loss either due to compression or to metadata/edit removal. Thanks

Comment: I edited my question to add clarity, again thanks.